# PBC libraries implementation

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cryptography, header-files

I am trying to implement a cryptography code and for that I need to include the pbc libraries into my code the basic code is as follows

```
#include "pbc.h"

int main(void)
{
/* call PBC functions */
    return 0;
    printf("it's there");
}
```

and I am working in ubuntu environment and after installing the pbc and gmu I am using this command

```
gcc -o foo foo.c -I home/Mtech/Desktop/Alok/pbc-0.5.14/include/pbc/ -L home/Mtech/Desktop/Alok/pbc-0.5.14/include/ -l pbc
```

but the system shows me the following error

```
:~/Desktop/Alok$ gcc -o foo foo.c -I home/Mtech/Desktop/Alok/pbc-0.5.14/include/pbc/ -L home/Mtech/Desktop/Alok/pbc-0.5.14/include/ -l pbc
foo.c:1:17: fatal error: pbc.h: No such file or directory
`enter code here`compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Although the cryptography tag is helpful, you should edit this question and place more tags on it for the language you are writing in and operating system. This will make your question more visible and hopefully get an answer.

Comment: There is no such directory as `~/Desktop/Alok/home/Mtech/Desktop/Alok/pbc-0.5.14/include/pbc/`.
So change `-I home/...` to `-I /home/...`. After that, you will also find
that `libpcb.so` and `libpcb.a` are not located in `/home/Mtech/Desktop/Alok/pbc-0.5.14/include/`,
where your `-L` option tells the linker to look for them, but in `/home/Mtech/Desktop/Alok/pbc-0.5.14/.libs`

Answer (score 0):

install gmp library first

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

install pbc library,pbc uses gmp library
[download]: https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/download.html "follow guide for installation"

for compiling

```
gcc <program_name>.c  -lgmp  -lpbc
```

for c++

```
g++ <program_name>.cpp  -lgmp -lgmpxx -lpbc
```

run

```
./a.out
```